# What is causing this "cannot be interpreted as an integer" error?

Tags: python, exception

It's probably something stupid that I'm missing but:
I'm getting this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Programming\Python\Windows\Console\ProjectHashDec\ProjectHashDec\ProjectHashDec.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(str(j) + ": " + str(int(hex(convertNumbers[j]), times)))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I don't know why this code doesn't work:

```
print("How many hexadecimal numbers do you want to input?")
print("A: 8")
print("B: 16")
print("C: 32")
print("D: 64")

choice = input("What do you choose? > ")
times = 0

if (choice == "A"):
    times = 8
elif (choice == "B"):
    times = 16
elif (choice == "C"):
    times = 32
elif (choice == "D"):
    times = 64`

convertNumbers = []
i = 0
j = 0

while i < times:
    i += 1
    convertNumbers.append(input(str(i) + ": "))

while j < times:
    j += 1
    print(str(j) + ": " + str(int(hex(convertNumbers[j]), times)))
```

Comment: What you wrote is **not** valid python. There is a single backtick at `times = 64` which would cause a `SyntaxError`. Please post the actual code you are using. In any case, my guess would be that `times` is actually a string: `>>> int('10', 'hello')
Traceback[...] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In creating one, you'll probably solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

in order to get your code to be able to run, you need to remove the backtick at times = 64 (will give you syntax error), remove the "int" (int will not work on hex numbers), and change the index call to convertnumbers (first index is 0 not 1).

I'll not change anything else in your code, but there are a few easy things you could do to improve the code. For instance  you could consider adding a logic for what happens if the userinput is not a,b,c or d, specifying that all input should be string, reduce while loop and required amount of userinputs.

```
print("How many hexadecimal numbers do you want to input?")
print("A: 8")
print("B: 16")
print("C: 32")
print("D: 64")

choice = input("What do you choose? > ")
times = 0

if (choice == "A"):
   times = 8
elif (choice == "B"):
   times = 16
elif (choice == "C"):
   times = 32
elif (choice == "D"):
   times = 64

convertNumbers = []
i = 0
j = 0

while i < times:
    i += 1
    convertNumbers.append(input(str(i) + ": "))

while j < times:
    j += 1
    print(str(j) + ": " + str((hex(convertNumbers[j-1]), times)))
```